# interpreting cluster results on text

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, k-means

I am a beginner picking up machine learning and starting with k means clusters on text documents

I achieved this by creating a tf-idf matrix, calculating cosine similarity, and then fitting.

Following a tutorial, I used multidimensional scaling (which is black magic to me), but Matplotlib yielded data where a cluster is graphed on the outer circle.

Any ideas on interpreting what went wrong or what this means?

I have not included any code. I imagine readers will want clarification on a few key points. Of which I will attempt to answer

1. What is the data? Job descriptions for startups
2. Max/Min DFs? .85 and .2 respectively
3. Process for constructing graph?

   a. use MDS to transform 1- cosineSimilarity of TFIDF matrix

   b. plot with pandas

Should I attempt ward hierarchical clustering or LDA?

[image: k means clustering on documents]